# Homepage Rich Snippets

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to display Rich Snippets for my store which is working fine for products and categories but it does not display rating/reviews for my website/homepage.

Below is my code

```
<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
  <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
  <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
</span>
```

Is it something I am doing wrong or Google does not allow this for homepage?

Answer (score 1):

No, review rich snippets should only be used in cases where "the main topic of the page needs to be about a specific product or service." -- using them on your homepage in general wouldn't be like that.

Comment: What should be the correct way if I want to display rating of the services I provide on my website?

Comment: You will have to put them on a leaf page; rich snippets will not work on the homepage.

Comment: @methode do you have a reference for rich snippets not working on the home page?

Comment: I don't think we have it documented anywhere; probably we should fix that, or make it more visible if we do have it documented.

Answer (score 1):

your rating/review data does not contain all the elements needed fot the ratings to be shown. For example, there is a highest possible rating value `bestRating` of 5, but what is the lowest possible value?

What Product or Service are you actually rating (or reviewing)? Unless your microdata is very clearly linked to it then it won't understand - you probably want them to rate a http://schema.org/Service you provide, or to rate your business with http://schema.org/LocalBusiness or http://schema.org/Organization - so nest it inside another schema. The property `aggregateRating` is available within these, which you could use, semantically it means you are rating the `Place` ie the business at that location. I can't see any reason why this would not work.

What google actually says is on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews?hl=en&rd=1

> We support reviews and ratings for a wide range of schema.org types, including businesses, products, and different creative works such as books or movies. When Google finds valid reviews or ratings markup, we may show a rich snippet that includes stars and other summary info from reviews or ratings.

Later on it is clear you can rate a LocalBusiness:

> Make sure the review or ratings markup refers clearly to a specific product or service as shown in the examples above. Do this by nesting the review or ratings within the markup of another schema.org type — such as schema.org/Book or schema.org/LocalBusiness — or by using that schema.org typed element as a value for the itemReviewed property.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Google's guidelines, Rich Snippet is not for home page. Here's a response from Google's Webmaster Trend analyst John Mueller in this reference:

> No, review rich snippets should only be used in cases where "the main
>   topic of the page needs to be about a specific product or service." --
>   using them on your homepage in general wouldn't be like that.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69292/rich-snippets-review-rating-on-homepage/69408#69408

Comment: this link from stackexchange points to text which has changed since the answer was posted (in 2014) - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews?hl=en&rd=1 which now 
> We support reviews and ratings for a wide range of schema.org types, including businesses, products, and different creative works such as books or movies. When Google finds valid reviews or ratings markup, we may show a rich snippet that includes stars and other summary info from reviews or ratings.