# Multiple rich snippets on homepage?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I am creating a website form my enterprise and I wonder how/how many snippets I should use on my homepage.

I know they are separate into multiple categories such as
local business or more generic organization, events, product etc.

I have read this post:
[Homepage Rich Snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595823/homepage-rich-snippets)
And this one:
[Multiple Schema.org Product items & how will it look like in search engine result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174785/multiple-schema-org-product-items-how-will-it-look-like-in-search-engine-resul)

In my case on my homepage (let's say index.html) I want to present my activity, put some links to the services/products I propose, and show incoming events.

Which snippet(s) should I use?

1) Only one such as organization? (my services are not available directly so I suppose it is not a local business category)

2) Or should I put several snippets: organization + event + products 
because all three categories are described/present on my homepage?

Comment: Did you read the answer to the first question you link to? It says that Google doesn’t show Rich Snippets for the homepage. -- About the terminology: Rich Snippets are enhanced result snippets in Google Search. You don’t "add" Rich Snippets to your page, you add structured data via the Schema.org vocabulary, and Google Search might (or might not) pick your structured data up to show a Rich Snippet they consider appropriate.

Comment: My apologies, i have missed that part, I just noticed that JSON-LD is not fully supported yet (but i am pretty sure it will be soon, because is very convenient method) . Ok, so i will describe with "structured data" ;-) the informations/webpages i consider valuable and the rest will be up on google. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[According to a Google employee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616800/1591669), Google Search won’t show Rich Snippets for homepages. But this is not documented, and it might change anytime.

From the perspective of Schema.org, it’s fine to provide as much data as possible. If you have multiple entities on your homepage, you can use multiple Schema.org types to describe them.

If one of these entities can be considered the primary entity (for example, on an organization’s website it would typically be the entity for the organization itself), you can use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) for it.